# spring batch remote partitioning How can i keep slave running ,listening the mq

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on spring batch remote partitioning .I want to run a slave listening the activemq . Then run a master to send msg to activemq.But when i run java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=slave app.jar .It just complete,not running in the jvm.How can i keep slave running ,listening the mq.

Comment: It is difficult to guess what can go wrong in this situation. Please share your example so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of code for worker. When you launch this code, worker wait instruction from the queue JMS. I hope it will help you.

```
@Profile("worker")
@EnableBatchIntegration
public class WorkerPartitioningConfig extends JmsWorkerConfig {

    // Bean declared inside @EnableBatchIntegration
    @Autowired
    public RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory;

    private Integer chunkSize = 100;

    private String directoryTemp = "/data/temp";


   /**
     * Reader
     */
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Data> reader(@Value("# {stepExecutionContext['filename']}") String fileName) {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Data>()
                .name("readerData")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(fileName))
                .targetType(Data.class)
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(",")
                .names(new String[]{"id", "text"})
                .encoding("UTF-8")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Writer
     */
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Data> fileToWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<Data> csv= new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Data>()
                .name("writer")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(directoryTemp + "/data-out-" + StringHelper.getRandomString() + ".csv"))
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(";")
                .names(new String[]{"id", "text"})
                .encoding("UTF-8")
                .build();
        csv.setAppendAllowed(true);
        csv.setShouldDeleteIfExists(false);
        csv.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(false);
        return csv;
    }

    /**
     * Worker step.
     */
    @Bean
    public Step workerStep() {
        return workerStepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                .inputChannel(requests())
                .outputChannel(replies())
                .<Data, Data>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(reader(null))
                .processor(new UpperCaseProcessor())
                .writer(fileToWriter())
                .build();
    }
}
```